# How do I control object distribution on surface with a texture in Geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have been following a tutorial on creating Sugar gumdrops with the sugar crystals on the surface.

I have tried to drive the placement of sugar crystals using a texture. This all worked fine in the older blender3D, but with all the changes done to Geo nodes, I can not figure out how do this in the new belnder 3.4! basically control the placement of these scattered objects on a mesh, but do it via a painted texture, simply white and black texture.

Can anyone help? here is the geo tree.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any attribute stored on, or calculated from, the mesh, to control the density of GN point-distribution. For example...

- A vertex-group, weight-painted:

[image]

- An image-texture, texture-painted (given a UV map):

[image]

- A procedural 3D texture:

[image]

.. and others.

Instead of using Named Attributes, you could feed the parameter out to the modifier / node-group interface, so the user can make the choice at the time, when re-using the modifier / sub-group.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved it for me, and also helped me to understand more about Geo nodes 